# What are these //!+ //!- tags in golang?

Tags: go, compilation, tags

I am reading [The Go Programming Language](http://www.informit.com/store/go-programming-language-9780134190587), and while browsing the source code I find certain tags, like:

```
//!+
//!-
```

or

```
//!+main
//!-main
```

Do they mean something to the compiler?

Comment: Can you post a few examples where you found these?

Comment: For example here: https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch7/bytecounter/main.go

Comment: These aren't part of the language or build chain. Most likely its for some type of display markup

Comment: The example you posted is not handled by the standard go tools. They are most likely inserted by a generator for debugging purposes, or they are intended for an automatic processor tool which may use these when generating documentation or some other output. They are not standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those comments don't mean something to the Go compiler. As stated in the [gopl.io](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io) project's `README.md`:

> Many of the programs contain comments of the form //!+ and //!-. These comments bracket the parts of the programs that are excerpted in the book; you can safely ignore them. In a few cases, programs have been reformatted in an unnatural way so that they can be presented in stages in the book.

For instance all code between the two snippets `//!+bytecounter` and `//!-bytecounter` are in the `gopl.io/ch7/bytecounter` snippet shown on p. 173 of the book.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like conditional compilation, it means that you can choose what sections to build when you build for multi platform, for example you can 
state:

```
// +build windows
```

for windows and etc
you can find more information about it and the full list here:

[http://blog.ralch.com](http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-conditional-compilation/)

also take a look at the build go package:

https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Comment: It's not the correct answer, but it does look like it, and it is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

wont be compiled on run time , i think it still considered as a comment